# Android updating marketplace app using a different signing key

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, signing

Developer signed an app with his personal keystore but it should have been the company's keystore.

Is it possible to update the app in the marketplace using the company's keystore now, and still having streamlined updates to users? Are there any consequences of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you will have to publish the app as a new app in the market. This time signed with the company's key. You will also have to change the package name as it is already used by the app which is already in the store.

When you try to update a app with a version that was signed with a different key Android will show an error to the user telling that the signature doesn't validate.

Comment: Okay, so steps needed would be to 1) delete the old app from the marketplace 2) change the package name of the project 3) sign with proper key and upload.

Comment: You cannot delete an application from the marketplace, you can unpublish it thought

Comment: @HandlerExploit Can you elaborate on how this is done? I just googled it but the Android publishing page doesn't elaborate on "unpublishing", how does the removal process work and what does it really do

Comment: Regarding unpublishing. This is just an obvious option in the Google Play Developer Console. It just removes access to the app. Existing users will not anything but it will be impossible to search for that exact act on the store. Dead simple to re-publish too, just click a button on the Developer Console and wait a few hours. You will be able to deliver updates again.

Comment: @Flo, i tried this, but the resulting file becomes 0 KB. could you please tell me the exact procedure? thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to change the signature now that it is in the marketplace. Google's only response will be to change the package name and upload it as a separate application.