# how to update my apk alone,without closing my older apps?

Tags: java, android, google-play

I put my apps in google play store,due to some reasons,its showing some error.Now i did those correction and i want to update the new apk,without reducing my older download numbers and their ratings and comments.Is this possible to update apk without reducing the older downloads

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ibetter.recipestutors"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your app, simply export a new apk and sign it with the same certificate as your origianl apk. Make sure you've incremented the version code.

Updating an app will have no effect on its download count. Your app will still have the same download statistics, and any users who still have it installed will receive an update notification via Google Play which will allow them to update the app.

Comment: @Maruthi042 That's the only thing you have to change. The version name can remain the same, or can be changed. Up to you. The package name cannot be changed

Comment: ,thank you,i want to change my version code as 1.2 or what i want to put

Comment: can i create new sign apk for my apps,because i forget my alias name

Comment: @Maruthi042 Your version code must be an integer like 1, 2, 3 and so on. You can't create a new signing key, as then your app can't be updated in Google Play. If you forgot your alias, then you must change your package name and publish the app as a new app. You will lose your download if you publish with a new package name

Answer (score 1):

You just have to increase your application version code in the manifest. But keep the same package name:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dont change the package name"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="increase by 1 every time you want to upload new apk"
    android:versionName="this can remain same but better change depending on the versionCode"
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ibetter.recipestutors"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

Comment: Versioning:
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html
Uploading:
http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-update-your-app-in-google-play

Comment: Yes. So increase the `versionCode to 2` and `versionName to 1.2` or you can keep it same if the change is too minor. Everything else like package name, keystroke etc.. will remain same. And if you care for, add something to the **What is new** section while uploading the APK, so that user will know what is added or changed in the new version, to make a decision on whether to update their current version or not.

Comment: actually some bugs is there in my older one,i edit that one,now i want to put the same apps with same name,but the corrected one,thats alone i need,i want to unpublish the older one?

Comment: one more things,i forgot the alias name,is this ok to create new sign apk

Comment: You have to **Upload** the new version ---> **Deactivate** the previous version and **Activate** the newly uploaded apk and **save**. So, in **What's new** you can add something like **Fixed so and so bug** etc

Comment: I think you cannot use a different keystroke to sign the same application. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106680/android-updating-marketplace-app-using-a-different-signing-key

Comment: actually i want to update my apk only,not more work,without gone my older downloading count

Comment: if i deactivate the previous version,my count will lost or not?

Comment: Your app's download count, rating, review etc.. will not change no matter how many version you upload. And no, if you deactivate the older version, your count will still remain.

Comment: But since you lost the alias name, and want to use a new keystroke, you will have to upload as a complete new application. In which case you will lose all of them.

Comment: actually i forgot my alias key

Comment: Is this i want to unpublish the older one,or if any one wants to download it will automatically comes new one?